# Adjust output based on the count of a substring within a string in a 2d char array

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, printf

I'm reading a bunch of lines from a file and trying to print each line that contains a certain set of keywords. Right now my code just looks for the first occurrence of a keyword within a line, if it finds one, it will print that keyword and that line with its line number. But I'm trying to make it so that if the line contains more than one occurrence of the keyword, then in the printed output, there should be a star character next to the line number. I've tried many different approaches and nothing seems to work. Here's my code:

```
for(i = 0; i < wordCount_keyword; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j <= lineCount; j++) {
        if(strstr(inputLines[j], keywords[i]) != NULL) {
            printf("%-*s %s (%d)\n", max_length + 1, keywords_upper[i], inputLines[j], j+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my current output:

```
CAT       the fish a dog cat dog rabbit (1)
CAT       the fish and cat  (2)
DOG       the fish a dog cat dog rabbit (1)
ELEPHANT  a rabbit or elephant (3)
FISH      the fish a dog cat dog rabbit (1)
FISH      the fish and cat  (2)
RABBIT    the fish a dog cat dog rabbit (1)
RABBIT    a rabbit or elephant (3)
```

Here's the ideally correct output I'm aiming for:

```
CAT       the fish a dog cat dog rabbit (1)
CAT       the fish and cat  (2)
DOG       the fish a dog cat dog rabbit (1*)
ELEPHANT  a rabbit or elephant (3)
FISH      the fish a dog cat dog rabbit (1)
FISH      the fish and cat  (2)
RABBIT    the fish a dog cat dog rabbit (1)
RABBIT    a rabbit or elephant (3)
```

Notice the difference being the star next to the 1 in paranthesis at the end of the 3rd line. 
What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there are no build-in functions in c to count the number of occurrences of a word in a string you need to write one. Let's say the definition of the function is "getWordOccurances(char * str, char * toSearch)". Then the following code will solve your problem.

```
for(i = 0; i < wordCount_keyword; i++) {
   for(j = 0; j <= lineCount; j++) {
       int count = getWordOccurances(inputLines[j], keywords[i]);
       if(count > 0) {
           printf("%-*s %s (%d", max_length + 1, keywords_upper[i], inputLines[j], j+1);
           if(count > 1) printf("*)\n");
           else printf(")\n");
       }
   }
}
```

And the getWordOccurances(char * str, char * toSearch) function may look like following:

```
int countOccurrences(char * str, char * toSearch){
    int i, j, found, count;
    int stringLen, searchLen;

    stringLen = strlen(str);      // length of string
    searchLen = strlen(toSearch); // length of word to be searched

    count = 0;

    for(i=0; i <= stringLen-searchLen; i++) {
        /* Match word with string */
        found = 1;
        for(j=0; j<searchLen; j++) {
            if(str[i + j] != toSearch[j]) {
                found = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(found == 1) count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Let me know if you don't understand any part of the program. Happy coding!